# How can I assign a list of items from database to the object for render in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to render a page with the code:

```
exports.new = function(req, res){
  res.render('products/new', {
    title: 'New Product',
    product: new Product({}),
    categories: Category.list()
  })
}
```

Category is a Mongoose schema. If I try to get list of all categories, it works asynchronously.

How I can get the list of all categories from a Mongo DB using Mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know, DB queries in Node are always asynchronous; so, you'll need to wait for the query to complete and then render your template in its callback!
In the end, it will be something like this:

```
Category.list(function( err, categories ) {
  res.render("products/new", {
    title: "New Product",
    product: new Product({}),
    categories: categories
  });
});
```